# TestDriven.Net not loading in Visual Studio -> Options, and also throwin an object reference error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tdd, testdriven.net

I installed the appropriate version of testdriven.net, but the context menu options are not visible. Also, this happens when I try to look around in VS (it's Enterprise edition if it helps).

[This is what is shown in the Tools -> Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzwCu.png)

[And this is what happens when I go to Help -> TestDriven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kieFP.png)

I tried reinstalling the testdriven, using more versions, deleting ComponentModelCache directory, running devenv /setup... to no avail.